# How do i make c threads do cyclyc sum?

Tags: c, multithreading, sum

So i have this program im working on, and the guist of it is that i need to do some operations with threads, following the next shcheme: The j-th thread Hj calculates a group of 100 consecutive iterations of the sum, making a cyclic distribution of the groups among all the threads. For example, if H = 4, the
thread H2 does the calculation of iterations [100..199, 500..599, 900..999, ...].
To ensure no data races occur, the threads must work each on a different sum variable.
Then compare after joining the threads the result achieved by the threads and the one done sequentally.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

#define H 4

double res[H] = {0};


//Time function

float restar_tiempo(struct timeval *inicio, struct timeval *fin) {
    return (fin->tv_sec - inicio->tv_sec) + 1e-6 * (fin->tv_usec - inicio->tv_usec);
}

//Thread function
void *_hilo(void *arg) {
    int a = * ((int*)arg);

    double pi = 0;

    double n = 100 * a;
    while (n < 10000000) {
        res[a] += (pow(-1, n) / pow(4, n)) * ((2 / (4 * n + 1)) + (2 / (4 * n + 2)) + (1 / (4 * n + 3)));
        pi++;
        n++;
        if ((int) n % 100 == 0)
            n += (H - 1)*100;
    }  
    printf("Result on thread[%d]: %f\n", a, res[a]);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main() {
    pthread_t hilo[H];
    struct timeval in, mid, fin;

    gettimeofday(&in, NULL);
    for (int i = 0; i < H; i++) {

        int* p = malloc(sizeof (int));
        *p = i;
        printf("Esto es i: %d\n", i);
        res[i] = 0;

        if (pthread_create(&hilo[i], NULL, _hilo,  p) != 0) {
            perror(" Error creando hilo");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        free(p);
    }

    //Join
    for (int i = 0; i < H; i++)
        pthread_join(hilo[i], NULL);


    //Partial sum
    double f = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < H; i++){
        printf("Resultado parcial de hilo %d: %f\n", i, res[i]);
        f += res[i];
    }
    //Total partial sum
    printf("Resultado total: %lf\n", f);
    //printf("Hola/n");
    gettimeofday(&mid, NULL);


    //Secuential sum
    double s = 0;
    for (double n = 0; n < 10000000; n++)
        s += (pow(-1, n) / pow(4, n)) * ((2 / (4 * n + 1)) + (2 / (4 * n + 2)) + (1 / (4 * n + 3)));


    //Print secuential
    printf("Resultado secuencial: %f\n", s);
    gettimeofday(&fin, NULL);

    //Result diff
    printf("Diferencia resultados: %f\n", fabs(f - s));

    //Time threads
    printf("Tiempo por hilos: %f\n", restar_tiempo(&in, &mid));

    //Secuential time
    printf("Tiempo secuencial: %f\n", restar_tiempo(&mid, &fin));

    //Time diff
    printf("Diferencia tiempos: %f\n", restar_tiempo(&in, &mid) - restar_tiempo(&mid, &fin));

    return 0;
}
```

I can compile everything without warnings, but when i execute the program, the result provided by the first thread is erratic, as it changes between executions (the rest of threads display 0 because they work with very little values).
Example with some added prints inside the thread function and after doing the join:

```
First execution:

This is i:0
This is i:1
This is i:2
This is i:3
//Inside thread funct
Thread result[2]: 0.000000
Thread result[2]: 0.000000
Thread result[3]: 0.000000
Thread result[0]: 3.141593
//After join
Partial result of thread 0: 3.141593
Partial result of thread 1: 0.000000
Partial result of thread 2: 0.000000
Partial result of thread 3: 0.000000
Total result: 3.141593
Sequential result: 3.141593
Difference results: 0.000000
Time per threads: 0.183857
Sequential time: 0.034788
Difference times: 0.149069

Second execution:

This is i:0
This is i:1
This is i:2
This is i:3
Thread result[2]: 0.000000
Thread result[0]: 6.470162
Thread result[0]: 6.470162
Thread result[3]: 0.000000
Partial result of thread 0: 6.470162
Partial result of thread 1: 0.000000
Partial result of thread 2: 0.000000
Partial result of thread 3: 0.000000
Total result: 6.470162
Sequential result: 3.141593
Difference results: 3.328570
Time per threads: 0.189794
Sequential time: 0.374017
Difference times: -0.184223
```

How can i make it so the sum works properly?
I think it has something to do with arg in the function _hilo, or the subsequent int cast with int a.
(Excuse the mix in languages, i speak spanish so most of the printfs are in said language. Dont mind them, the block with the results example has the traduction)

Comment: Look at how small 1/4^n is. The values the threads other than thread 0 calculate are too small to show up in the digits that `%f` prints. You can use `%g` to see their values, but they will still be too small to change the total sum.

Comment: I just realized that as you answered. Still, the first thread does not work properly, ill update the example with another case.

Answer (score 0):

Okay i solved it but i dont know why it works like this fully or why this caused issues. I just deleted the `free (p)`  statement and now it works like a charm. If someone can enlighten me on why this happens, i´ll be grateful.

Comment: You should not free memory in the main thread that has been allocated for a subthread to use until the thread is done using it (or free it in the subthread, not in the main thread). It takes some time for the thread to start and to read the value passed to it in that memory, and, if you free it before that, that memory may get reallocated and used for another purpose.

Comment: Thank you very much, i will take it into consideration for the next time :)